Deploying ROS bridge on Ubuntu 20.04
I need to run some application based on ROS 1 which requires to communicate with another application based on ROS 2. I have installed ROS 1 on the Ubuntu 20 host. I wanted to run ROS 2 in the docker container, to avoid any interference. Where should I install the ROS bridge? Can I run it also as Docker container? because it requires access to ROS 1 and ROS2?

This article/tutorial should solve your problem.
This is the Docker file config.
Do not worry about ROS 1 and ROS 2 conflicts, setting the alias differently and sourcing them separately will ensure that they do not conflict.
The bridge is between ROS 1 neotic and ROS 2 foxy as both support Ubuntu 20.04, you can try Ros2 humble, but at least personally it does not play well with bridging, if you really need it then try the offical ROS docs.

Thank you. OK I will have a try. My other ROS 2 application might not support Ubuntu 20, while the other ROS 1 based does. I am wondering if putting the bridge together with ROS 2 in a docker container with the other application, while ROS 1 is on the host is also way to go?

Yes, that would be right as well, depending on what you need. You can put ros1, ros2 in different docker images and put the bridge in either  and expose the docker images to each other and make ros communicate via the bridge via the exposed docker parts of the docker image.
